# Read Azure event-Hub older data

Tags: azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub

Read  Azure event-Hub older data. (Older data date > retention Period-7 days)
Is there any way to read event hub based on date ?
Need Python or Scala functions.

FYI, am processing events in azure databricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consumers cannot read data older than the retention policy period. If you think you may need to process older data, I recommend turning on capture for your eventhubs. Check below for more information on the capture feature.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview

Comment: But it captures in avro format